# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /app/db/schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run `rake db:migrate` on my ec2 instance. I have a RDS postgres instance.

`Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /app/db/schema.rb`**

below are the relevant contents of my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update

RUN useradd -m deploy

WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir -p vendor
COPY vendor/cache vendor/cache
RUN bundle install --deployment --local --without test development
COPY . .

RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE=111 RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile

RUN mkdir -p tmp/pids
RUN chown -R deploy tmp log

USER deploy
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT 1

EXPOSE 3000
CMD bin/rake db:migrate && bundle exec passenger start --address 0.0.0.0 --port 3000 --auto --disable-anonymous-telemetry -e production
```

here is my deployment yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eks-learning-backend
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: eks-learning-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rails-app
        image: zzz.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/eks:16
        env:
        - name: EKS_DATABASE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: database-config
              key: database_name
        - name: EKS_DATABASE_HOST
          value: zzz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
        - name: EKS_DATABASE_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: database-config
              key: username
        - name: EKS_DATABASE_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: database-config
              key: password
        - name: RAILS_MASTER_KEY
          value: zzxx
        - name: RAILS_ENV
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

Any help in this would be really great! Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the user is not have permission to access the file. What happens when you build the dockerfile and run it from your local machine using "docker run -it image"

Comment: hi @RajanPanneerSelvam, i see no error when i run the image on local machine. it looks like the deploy user is unable to create files in the cluster / container.

Comment: Are you sure you have the required secrets - kubectl get secrets?

Comment: yes, i have, i also verified that i am able to access the secrets inside the container

Comment: I agree with the idea of insufficient user permissions. You might need to chown `/app/db/` dir also. As for now I can only see you execute `RUN chown -R deploy tmp log`. Please check that and let me know if that is the case.

Comment: hi @OhHiMark, thanks for your reply. Actually, yes that fixed the issue. I am actually migrating application from `GCP` to `AWS` and on GCP there is no such issue, but when i port to `AWS` i get the above error. do you know if could be something AWS specific.

Comment: It is hard to tell without more details about both environments. You can ask that in another question providing more details. As for this one I will compose an answer based on my previous comment as it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the user has insufficient permissions. You only included `RUN chown -R deploy tmp log` while you also need to give it access to `/app/db/` dir. 
Adding additional `chown` for the DB dir will solve the issue.

Comment: sorry for the delay in this, have accepted the answer.